# Typehinting function with two possible call signatures

Tags: python, types, mypy

I have a class which takes a function as a parameter, and I want that function to either have signature `int -> int` or `list[int] -> int`. I've type hinted it using a `Union` as follows.

```
from typing import Callable, Union

class Foo:
    def __init__(self, func: Callable[[Union[int, list[int]]], int]) -> None:
        self.func = func

def identity(num: int) -> int:
    return num

Foo(identity)
```

Unfortunately mypy is not happy with the final line (`Foo(identity)`), saying

```
 error: Argument 1 to "Foo" has incompatible type "Callable[[int], int]"; expected "Callable[[Union[int, List[int]]], int]"
```

I understand now that the `identity` function signature does not match exactly the typehint for `func`, but I'm stuck as to how to move forward here. What is the proper way to handle this scenario?

Comment: You can use `@overload` to declare multiple signatures.

Comment: TIL `@overload`! Very cool. I'm not sure it's the best use for me here, but this is really great to know about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should annotate the parameter with a Union of the two different Callable signatures

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, func: Union[Callable[[int], int], Callable[[list[int]], int]]) -> None:
        self.func = func
```

Comment: Ahh I see. Seems more obvious in hindsight!

Comment: @lainShelvington what if instead of the function taking `int` or `list[int]`, the argument type was itself a union (e.g. `Union[int, float]`)? I realize I abstracted this away while creating my MWE.

Comment: @natty then the passed function would have to take the same union as a parameter - `def identity(num: int|float) -> int:`

Comment: Is it possible to show mypy `int -> int` is a subtype of `(int | float) -> int`? In my code the `identity` function goes on to use properties of `int`s, and hence typehinting `num` as a union will be incorrect.